# SQL left JOIN with 4 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

i have two tables

```
IDartist     name
----------- -----------
1           akon
2           50 cent

IDsong    name   IDartist   IDauthor   IDcomposer   IDmusicProducer
------    ----   --------   --------   ---------    ---------------
1         lonley    1         2           1              2
```

how i out the name of whice IDartist,IDauthor,IDcomposer,IDmusicProducer ?

i tried to do this and its not working:

```
SELECT
songs.`IDsong`,
songs.`IDartist`,
songs.`name`,
songs.`IDgenre`,
songs.`IDauthor`,
songs.`IDcomposer`,
songs.`IDmusicProducer`,
artists.`name` As artists_name,
songs_genres.`name` As genres_name
FROM `songs`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `artists` ON (songs.`IDartist` = artists.`IDartist` OR songs.`IDauthor` = artists.`IDartist` OR songs.`IDcomposer` = artists.`IDartist` OR songs.`IDmusicProducer` = artists.`IDartist`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `songs_genres` ON (songs.`IDgenre` = songs_genres.`IDgenre`)
WHERE songs.`IDsong`=XXX
```

Comment: Use a single INNER JOIN

Comment: @Mihai, how would that solve this problem? (What *is* the problem, actually?)

Comment: @GolezTrol I did a highly scientific guess about his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the names of the artist, author, composer, and producer, you will have to join the `artists` table to the `songs` table for separate times.  The query should look something like the following:

```
SELECT
s.IDsong, s.name,
a1.name AS artists_name,
a2.name AS author_name,
a3.name AS composer_name,
a4.name AS producer_name,
sg.name AS genres_name
FROM songs AS s
  JOIN artists AS a1 ON s.IDartist = a1.IDartist
  JOIN artists AS a2 ON s.IDauthor = a2.IDartist
  JOIN artists AS a3 ON s.IDcomposer = a3.IDartist
  JOIN artists AS a4 ON s.IDmusicProducer = a4.IDartist
  JOIN songs_genres AS sg ON s.IDgenre = sg.IDgenre
```

If there may not be an artist, author, composer, and producer for a record then you will have to use `LEFT JOIN` on the tables instead.

Comment: Thanks is appreciated but not required.  If my answer worked for you then click on the check mark next to it to set it as the accepted answer.